# How to use Semidefinite Optimization for a problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

What is this error message and how can I make this `SemidefiniteOptimization` work?
Also, is there an easier way to input my constraint in terms of each element `X[i,j]`, for example can I simply use the `\[CapitalChi]` matrix directly?

[image: Screen shot of the image and the error message]

```
(* Creating a matrix of free parameters (8\[Cross]8) *)
\[CapitalChi] = Table[X[i, j], {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 8}];

(* Creating a random Hermitian matrix (8\[Cross]8) *)
\[ScriptCapitalW] = Module[{a}, (1/2)*((a = Table[RandomComplex[], {8}, {8}]) + ConjugateTranspose[a])];

(* Creating basis matrices (2\[Cross]4) matrices *)
Base[l_] := (1/Sqrt[2])*ArrayFlatten[{{UnitStep[-(l - 4 - 1/2)]*PauliMatrix[Mod[l - 1, 4]], UnitStep[l - 4 - 1/2]*PauliMatrix[Mod[l - 1, 4]]}}];

(* SDP *)
SemidefiniteOptimization[(-4^(-1))*Tr[\[ScriptCapitalW] . \[CapitalChi]], {Sum[X[i, j]*ConjugateTranspose[Base[i]] . Base[j], {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 8}] == IdentityMatrix[4], VectorGreaterEqual[{\[CapitalChi], 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 8}]}, ArrayFlatten[\[CapitalChi], 1]]
```